# Using EnableEvents and Case getting complicated and loop problems

Tags: vba, excel

I have in the sheet change event code. Encapsulated in Application.EnableEvents = False, I have some Case selections that get triggered. See Code and Image of sheet. All of what I have is working as is but I realized that I have not designed for some of the cells that need to be updated if D4 (Purchase Price) is changed.
ie: D14. I noticed that by clicking on the cell it will refresh with the new values calculated but a user would just expect that all calculations relevant will be updated automatically with the D4 change. There are a few other additional cells that the user may change after the other calculations have been done. such as Rental income which affects other cells.I have been going in circles trying to find where to enter these additional changes. 
I thought that I could just add  D14 = B14 * D4 in one the cases that would be appropriate but I keep getting unexpected loops and things. My logic just isn't up to figuring this out :( I don't want to confuse this anymore by showing the code that I have tried out. I have just included what is working before I realized that my sheet isn't complete. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: My sheet]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back

Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$D$5" ' Downpayment Entered
        range("B5") = (range("D5").Value / range("D4").Value) * 100
        Debug.Print "Percent " & range("B5").Value

    Case "$B$5" ' Percent Entered
        range("D5").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B5").Value) / 100
        Debug.Print "DownPayment " & range("D5").Value

    '2 cases for Rental Income
    Case "$C$9" ' Monthly Rental Entered
        range("D9") = (range("C9").Value * 12)
        Debug.Print "Monthly Rental Entered"

    Case "$D$9" ' Yearly Entered
        range("C9").Value = range("D9") / 12
          Debug.Print "Yearly Rental Entered"

    '3 cases for Vacancy Rate
    Case "$D$10" ' Yearly Vacancy Rate Entered
        range("C10").Value = range("D10") / 12
        range("B10").Value = range("D10").Value / range("D9") * 100
        Debug.Print "Yearly Vacancy Rate Entered"

    Case "$C$10" ' Monthly Vacancy Rate Entered
        range("D10").Value = range("C10").Value * 12
        range("B10").Value = range("D10").Value / range("D9") * 100
        Debug.Print "Monthly Vacancy Rate Entered "

    Case "$B$10" ' % Vacancy Rate Entered
        range("D10").Value = (range("D9").Value * range("B10").Value) / 100
        range("C10").Value = range("D10").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "% Vacancy Rate Entered "

    '3 cases for Property Tax Entered
    Case "$D$14" ' Yearly Prop Tax Entered
        range("B14").Value = range("D14").Value / range("D4") * 100
        range("C14").Value = range("D14").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Yearly Prop Tax Entered"

    Case "$C$14" ' Monthly Prop Tax Entered
        range("D14").Value = range("C14").Value * 12
        range("B14").Value = range("D14").Value / range("D4") * 100
        Debug.Print "Monthly Prop Tax Entered"

    Case "$B$14" ' Percent of Prop Tax Entered
        range("D14").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B14").Value) / 100
        range("C14").Value = range("D14").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Percent Prop Tax Entered"

    '3 cases for Property Management Entered
    Case "$D$15" ' Yearly Property Management Entered
        range("B15").Value = range("D15").Value / range("D9") * 100
        range("C15").Value = range("D15").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Yearly Prop Mgmt Entered"

    Case "$C$15" ' Monthly Property Management Entered
        range("D15").Value = range("C15").Value * 12
        range("B15").Value = range("D15").Value / range("D9") * 100
        Debug.Print "Monthly Prop Mgmt Entered"

    Case "$B$15" ' Percent of Property Management Entered
        range("D15").Value = range("D9").Value * range("B15").Value / 100
        range("C15").Value = range("D15").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Percent Prop Mgmt Entered"

    '3 cases for Insurance Entered
    Case "$D$16" ' Yearly Insurance Entered
        range("B16").Value = range("D16").Value / range("D4") * 100
        range("C16").Value = range("D16").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Yearly Prop Tax Entered"

    Case "$C$16" ' Monthly Insurance Entered
        range("D16").Value = range("C16").Value * 12
        range("B16").Value = range("D16").Value / range("D4") * 100
        Debug.Print "Monthly Prop Tax Entered"

    Case "$B$16" ' Percent of Insurance Entered
        range("D16").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B16").Value) / 100
        range("C16").Value = range("D16").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Percent Prop Tax Entered"

    '3 cases for Maintenance Entered
    Case "$D$17" ' Yearly Maintenance Entered
        range("B17").Value = range("D17").Value / range("D11") * 100
        range("C17").Value = range("D17").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Yearly Maintenance Entered"

    Case "$C$17" ' Monthly Maintenance Entered
        range("D17").Value = range("C17").Value * 12
        range("B17").Value = range("D17").Value / range("D11") * 100
        Debug.Print "Monthly Maintenance Entered"

    Case "$B$17" ' Percent of Maintenance Entered
        range("D17").Value = (range("D11").Value * range("B17").Value) / 100
        range("C17").Value = range("D17").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Percent Maintenance Entered"

    '3 cases for Other Expenses Entered
    Case "$D$18" ' Yearly Other Expenses Entered
        range("B18").Value = range("D18").Value / range("D11") * 100
        range("C18").Value = range("D18").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Yearly Other Expenses Entered"

    Case "$C$18" ' Monthly Other Expenses Entered
        range("D18").Value = range("C18").Value * 12
        range("B18").Value = range("D18").Value / range("D11") * 100
        Debug.Print "Monthly Other Expeneses Entered"

    Case "$B$18" ' Percent of Other Expeneses Entered
        range("D18").Value = (range("D11").Value * range("B18").Value) / 100
        range("C18").Value = range("D18").Value / 12
        Debug.Print "Percent Other Expeneses Entered"

  '2 cases for Mortgage Entered
  Case "$C$21" ' Monthly Entered
        range("D21") = (range("C21").Value * 12)
        Debug.Print "Monthly Mortgage Entered"

    Case "$D$21" ' Yearly Entered
        range("C21").Value = range("D21") / 12
          Debug.Print "Yearly Mortgage Entered"

End Select
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| enable events handling

End Sub
```

Comment: You'd be better off redesigning this to use formulas as much as possible.  I don't see any benefit in having to manage all of the calculations via VBA.  Apply a specific styling to the "input" cells so they're easily distinguished from the calculated values.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I am not clear on how this will help because there are so many input cells that interact with other input cells that recalculate another input cell. I am sure that there would be a much more elegant solution than mine that an experienced vba/excel programmer could do but with my limited knowledge and the very rare need for me to create a spreadsheet. I think I will leave well enough alone and bandaide it together. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ideally "inputs" and "outputs" are separate: if the user enters a value in one place, then entering/changing another value somewhere else shouldn't change that first input.  That would be pretty confusing for the end-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe adding this?

```
Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$D$4" 
        range("B5") = (range("D5").Value / range("D4").Value) * 100
        range("D5").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B5").Value) / 100
        range("B14").Value = range("D14").Value / range("D4") * 100
        range("D14").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B14").Value) / 100
        range("B16").Value = range("D16").Value / range("D4") * 100
        range("D16").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B16").Value) / 100
        ...
End Select
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| enable events handling
```

Comment: Yes, this did work. I have no idea what I was doing when it didn't work. I had some if then happening then the case would trigger etc. It was a nightmare.